# Unsatisfied Link error while using SQLCipher library

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I am using the SQLCipher Library for Android to Encrypt/Decrypt the DB file. I am following the exact steps that were discussed in the API to add the library.

But I am getting a Unsatisfied link error when i run the project... Here's the logcat...

```
11-15 13:12:08.482: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dbopen
11-15 13:12:08.482: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
11-15 13:12:08.482: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1876)
11-15 13:12:08.482: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:870)
11-15 13:12:08.482: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:904)
11-15 13:12:08.482: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:107)
11-15 13:12:08.482: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at com.myproject1.getInstance(AppData.java:60)
```

Please give me any reference or hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the .so files into the libs/armaebi folder of your eclipse project and rebuild.

Comment: What about if you've done that and still get the UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Answer (score 15):

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` happens when the SQLCipher library was not initialized before using.

To solve the problem, call `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);` before using.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);

    // Set up the window layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //instance of database adapter
    db = DBAdapter.getInstance(this);

    //load database
    db.load("password goes here");
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you share what version of SQLCipher for Android you are using?  We have recently released a new version of SQLCipher for Android with many changes.  If you are not currently up to date with the latest release you can get it [here](https://github.com/downloads/guardianproject/android-database-sqlcipher/SQLCipherForAndroid-SDK-0.0.6-RC1.tar.gz).

Comment: I've experienced this exception using SQLCipher v2.0 RC4. .so files are included in project...

Comment: ^ turns out it was yet another Eclipse bug causing this, whereby included libraries werent actually included.

Comment: @straya After following setfault's advice, I may have run into the same issue with sqlcipher v2.1.1.  It can't find "libraryName "stlport_shared" (id=830025040304)".  How did you get around this?

Comment: turns out the libraries have to be in folder "prj/libs" (plural) not "prj/lib"...what a horrible dependency.