# Implement sqlcipher-for-android

Tags: android, sql, sqlcipher

Hi I  try to implement sql cipher. I use the code from github from here(https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher). Extract the source code and import it into eclipse. But it's not running. I got the following exception . Please anyone tell me what i've done wrong?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:120)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:115)
    at example.SQLDemoActivity.onCreate(SQLDemoActivity.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: [Try this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8428203)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
Initially i forgot to add `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, `x86` folders. Which contains .so files.

In `armeabi`:

```
libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
libsqlcipher_android.so
libstlport_shared.so
```

In `armeabi-v7a`:

```
libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
libsqlcipher_android.so
libstlport_shared.so
```

In `x86`:

```
libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
libsqlcipher_android.so
libstlport_shared.so
```

I've add armeabi, armeabi-v7a,x86. folders in libs now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is not properly including the native .so files with your application.  These are required for SQLCipher for Android to operate.  They should be in a platform specific folder beneath the `libs` folder.  As a reference, please review the project structure of the SQLCipher for Android [test suite](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests).

Comment: What is that .so file ? Please tell me how to add .so file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download a .zip package and copy-paste libs no more. Just [add a Gradle dependency](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-add-sqlcipher-to-your-android-app/), like `compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.3.1-2@aar'`. [Here](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22android-database-sqlcipher%22) you can always check the latest version.